# How to use Xdebug on linux hosting bought

Tags: php, xdebug

Is it possible to install and use xdebug remotely by having a remote shared hosting (I havent' access to the terminal of the hosting)?

Comment: Maybe? Depends on the hosting.

Comment: I'm searching what are the administrative options on cpanel that permit it.

Comment: on shared hosting you'll need to contact the hosting provider if you don't have it in cpanel. i'm sure you can enable modules in cpanel, hopefully xdebug.